# android how to stop audio thread on button press?

Tags: android, multithreading, audio, audiotrack

I have a thread that uses AudioTrack to synthesize a sequence of notes, with a seekbar to change the tempo.

```
t = new Thread()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            setPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY);

            int buffersize = AudioTrack.getMinBufferSize(sr, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO,
                    AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);

            audiotrack = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, sr,
                    AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT,
                    buffersize, AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);

            short samples[] = new short[buffersize];

            int amplitude = 10000;
            double twopi = 2*Math.PI;

            double ph = 0.0;


            audiotrack.play();
            double r = 1.0594630943593; //the 12th root of 2
            frequency=261.63;
            for(int k = 1; k<9; k++) //number of notes played
            {
                frequency*=r;
                for (int i = 0; i < 4+4*temposliderval; i++) //duration of each note, if i = 50, note duration = 12 seconds
                {

                    for (int j = 0; j < buffersize; j++)
                    {
                        samples[j] = (short) (amplitude * Math.sin(ph));
                        ph += twopi * frequency / sr;
                    }
                    audiotrack.write(samples, 0, buffersize);
                }
            }

            audiotrack.stop();
            audiotrack.release();

        }
    };


    //play button
    play = (Button)findViewById(R.id.play);
    play.setBackgroundResource(R.mipmap.play);
    play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            t.start();
        }
    });







    //stop button
    stop = (Button)findViewById(R.id.stop);
    stop.setBackgroundResource(R.mipmap.stop);
    stop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            t.interrupt();
        }
    });
```

I want to be able to stop the audio when the stop button is pushed. Calling t.interrupt() doesn't work, so **I'm wondering how to properly stop the thread when the stop button is pushed.** The goal is to be able to stop the audio whenever desired, and start it back up again when the play button is pressed again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out! This method doesn't seem to be listed anywhere else, so I must have gotten pretty lucky:

Simply put the thread in a new method, and call that method on playbutton click, and rather than try to stop the thread, just stop the audiotrack's audio:

```
 play = (Button)findViewById(R.id.play);
    play.setBackgroundResource(R.mipmap.play);
    play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            playScale();
        }
    });







    //stop button
    stop = (Button)findViewById(R.id.stop);
    stop.setBackgroundResource(R.mipmap.stop);
    stop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            audiotrack.stop();
        }
    });
```

Now every time the play button is hit, the thread will simply restart, despite not being actually *stopped*.

```
public void playScale()
{
    t = new Thread()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            t.setPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY);

            int buffersize = AudioTrack.getMinBufferSize(sr, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO,
                    AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);

            audiotrack = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, sr,
                    AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT,
                    buffersize, AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);

            short samples[] = new short[buffersize];

            int amplitude = 10000;

            double twopi = 2 * Math.PI;

            double ph = 0.0;

            audiotrack.play();

            double r = 1.0594630943593; //the 12th root of 2

            frequency = 261.63;
            for (int k = 1; k < 9; k++) //number of notes played
            {
                frequency *= r;
                for (int i = 0; i < 4 + 4 * temposliderval; i++) //duration of each note, if i = 50, note duration = 12 seconds; minimum tempo = 60 bpm
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < buffersize; j++)
                    {
                        samples[j] = (short) (amplitude * Math.sin(ph));
                        ph += twopi * frequency / sr;
                    }
                    audiotrack.write(samples, 0, buffersize);
                }
            }
        }
    };
    t.start();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing to do might be to declare a `volatile` member variable:

```
private volatile boolean mStop = false;
```

that both threads have access to. You could poll the variable inside the inner the loop of the thread and stop looping when it gets set, and set the variable to true when the button is pressed.

Comment: Could you show me how you would do this within the code example I posted above? I only have one thread, by the way.

Comment: You have 2 threads. You created one, t, and there's the main UI thread that Android will call your onClick handlers on.